# Codeigniter Path called from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have two Codeigniter instances from which I'm executing Ajax calls in a View / Javascript file as shown below. In one instance the call is resolved to "http://www.myhost.com/myapp/index.php/api/api_controller/get.json" and on the other it is "http://www.myhost.com/myapp/api/api_controller/get.json" without the 'index.php'.

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks!

```
var url = "api/generic_item_api/get.json"

$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){       
           // do something          
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: could be a bunch of reasons.  One instance isn't using mod_rewrite, or your using relative paths, or config base url is different.....etc

Comment: Hi Rooster. Great comment. Can you let me know how I can check mod_rewrite and relative paths? config base url is correct.

Comment: check your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

By default codeigniter includes index.php in the url

you need to remove the index.php using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

check here (Removing the index.php file):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html